# Ratiometric ADC

Tags: adc

I know that mathematically the k-V analog input on an A to D converter could be converted to the digital code of \$\dfrac{k(2^n-1)}{VDD}\$. But I really don't understand where it comes from and the logic behind it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The values of a n-bit number range from 0 to 2**n-1.

Comment: yes but how we get to that formula in the question?

Comment: The minimum value is represented by 0V and the maximum value is represented by Vdd. The rest is just linear interpolation.

Comment: But the interpolation does not make sense. We are comparing resolution of the ADC (2^n-1) to the analogue reading

Comment: For example for a analog voltage of 2.12 volt the ADC will report 434 for a max of 5 volts. So we are using 1023 to get 434?

Comment: Shouldn't we use the value of the 1023 bit to get the result and not the actual "1023"?

Comment: You don't have 1023 bits. You have 10 bits. Which gives you 1024 values.

Comment: So why we use 1023 in our equation  instead of 1024 (if the value is 1024)?

Comment: Because 0 is a value too.

Comment: 1023 is the resolution I guess. We have 1023 levels to define our analogue voltage with binary codes

Comment: Technically you got 1024 levels. 0 trough 1023 maps voltages from 0 to Vref (or VDD)

Comment: I think my problem was that I didn't realize that the value of the 1024 level is 1023 because it is all ones. I think I get it now. Let me know if I am right.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: @Mary I think you should answer your own question and accept that anwser. That doesn't happen often but it is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I didn't realize that the value of the 1024 level is 1023 because it is all ones.